# Quickblox Android SDK : Login with facebook token issue

Tags: android, facebook, quickblox

I'm using Quickblox in my app and I can't signIn an user with Facebook token, here's how I create QB Session which works fine:

```
public static void createSession(final QBEntityCallback callback){
    QBAuth.createSession(new QBEntityCallbackImpl<QBSession>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(QBSession result, Bundle params) {
            callback.onSuccess();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(List<String> errors) {
            Log.e("QBSession", "error " + errors.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

When the user log in with facebook, the result token is not null but when I do this:

```
public static void registerUser(AccessToken currentAccessToken, final QBEntityCallbackImpl callback) {

    if (currentAccessToken == null)return;

    QBUsers.signInUsingSocialProvider(QBProvider.FACEBOOK, currentAccessToken.getToken(), null, new QBEntityCallbackImpl<QBUser>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(QBUser user, Bundle args) {
            callback.onSuccess(user, args);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(List<String> errors) {
            Log.e("error", "is " + errors.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

I get this in the logcat:

```
E/error﹕ is [base Login or email required]
```

[Here](http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-users-android#Sign_In_.26_Social_authorization) is the documents.

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**

In case it could help some people, here's how I do it now:

- First, I sign up this way, where Profile is the object from the facebook login callback:

  ```
   public static void signUpUser(Profile newProfile, final QBEntityCallbackImpl callback){

  QBUser qbUser = new QBUser();
  qbUser.setFullName(newProfile.getName());
  qbUser.setLogin(newProfile.getId());
  qbUser.setPassword(newProfile.getId());
  qbUser.setFacebookId(newProfile.getId());

  QBUsers.signUp(qbUser, new QBEntityCallbackImpl<QBUser>() {
      @Override
      public void onSuccess(QBUser result, Bundle params) {
          callback.onSuccess(result, params);
      }

      @Override
      public void onError(List<String> errors) {
          callback.onError(errors);
      }
  });
  ```

  }
- Once the user is created, he can now login using the signUpUsingSocialProvider :

  ```
  public static void signInUser(AccessToken currentAccessToken, final QBEntityCallbackImpl callback) {

  if (currentAccessToken == null)return;

  String facebookAccessToken = currentAccessToken.getToken();
  QBUsers.signInUsingSocialProvider(QBProvider.FACEBOOK, facebookAccessToken, null, new QBEntityCallbackImpl<QBUser>() {
      @Override
      public void onSuccess(QBUser user, Bundle args) {
          callback.onSuccess(user, args);
      }

      @Override
      public void onError(List<String> errors) {
          callback.onError(errors);
      }
  });
  ```

  }

So, the trick was to create the user the normal way before login with Facebook. Then it's possible for this user to login on another device just using his Facebook session.

Comment: please make sure that your token is not "null" and provide full console log

Comment: Thank you for replying. The token is definitely not null. Like I said in the update, I'm now able to create an user this way : I sign UP using the facebook Profile object and then signInUsingSocialProvider using the AccessToken and it works fine. Do you confirm that it's possible to create an user just using signInUsingSocialProvider with no call to signUp before?

Comment: have you solved it eventually ? I Have the same problem currently

Comment: @LiranRevivo Check my update, I added some code, I hope it helps !

Comment: Thanks this was helpful for me..

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a user when you would like to use social login

Just do the following things:

1. createSession
2. signInUsingSocialProvider

don't need to call signUp

Comment: i already did that but its not working i created a session with social provider in the success method im signing it through facebook provider its giving me always E/error﹕ is [base Login or email required]